# Writing an email validation function

Tags: javascript, validation

Write a function called `validate` that takes a single sting argument. The function should return true if and only if the string contains at least one dot `.` and exactly one `@` symbol.
E.g.

```
validate ("j.nicholson@southampton.ac.uk")===true
```

Comment: Sound like a school assignment. Read the doc, and show us some code! This is a one-liner!

Comment: This sounds very much like a homework/interview question - if this is the case it would be prudent to acknowledge and disclose this fact since the users of [so] are not really in the business of doing other peoples work for them. Show what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Small hint: try looking at [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: @Jakub Hampl How would indexOf help to verify there is only one '@' ?

Comment: The link pretty much answers that question if you actually read the page.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl seems like a lot of trouble for something that could be done with a simple regex

Comment: Indeed, regex are the way to go, but it takes some time to get used to it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I agree... but learning regex for a simple task like this is probably too much trouble for the OP.

Comment: I have an exam just doing some test question , and this one is really confusing , i have the answer, its just now working, so must be doing something wrong!

Comment: @AprilRobinson Can you provide the code for the validate function. Can't say where the function's going wrong without seeing the function!

Answer (score 0):

if you really need the answer, here it is...

```
var website = "x.John@example.com"
function validate(){
    var hasOneAtSymbol = false,
    hasDots = false;
    for(var i in website){
        if(website[i] === "@"){
            if(hasOneAtSymbol){
                return false;
            }else{
                hasOneAtSymbol = true;
            }
        }else if(website[i] === "."){
            hasDots = true;
        }
    }
    if(hasOneAtSymbol && hasDots){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as readability goes, this is well written. Conceptually, though, it could be improved: you can leverage some existing JavaScript `String` functions, making the `for` loop unecessary (not to mention the possibility of regexes, but that's another thing entirely).

Comment: Thank you! i missed out one of the else statements thank you for your time much appreciated  !!!

Comment: I like keeping my code simple and readable... that is all i care about :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is a homework assignment, I'll help you out.

There are a couple ways you can tackle this. Most of the time, when you are trying to validate some input, you use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). However, I can also think of two other ways: using [String's indexOf function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), or manually looping through the array of characters that make up the string.

Let's look at the `indexOf` function, which should be pretty straight forward.

In Javascript, there isn't a `contains` function when inspecting a string. This is a bit annoying, but you can create your own function using the `indexOf` function.

So, from MDN, the `str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])` function `returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.`

OK, so if `indexOf` returns non-negative value, our string contains the string we are searching for!

So, let's write a contains function.

```
function contains(original_string, string_to_search_for) {
    // if `location_of_search_string` is 0 or greater, we have a match.
    var location_of_search_string = original_string.indexOf(string_to_search_for);
    if (location_of_search_string >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With me so far? Now we can clean that code up a bit so it isn't so many lines. We can actually have it be one line. notice how if our `if` statement is `true`, we want to also return `true`? We can take advantage of this by just returning what the if statement evaluates to. We also don't need to store our result in a variable.

OK, so now we have

```
function contains(original_string, string_to_search_for) {
    return (original_string.indexOf(string_to_search_for) >= 0);
}
```

OK, so to see if our string has a `.` in it, we can run:

```
var email = 'hello@example.com';
contains(email, '.'); //returns true
```

Now, if we would run this against an ampersand (`@`), this will return true if it has *at least* one ampersand, but we want **only** one. So, we need another function.

There are a couple of ways you can do this, but let's stick with `indexOf`. Remember the `fromIndex` argument we can pass `indexOf`? Let's use that. After we find our first occurance of an `@`, let's start looking for another ampersand *after* that location. If we don't find any, then we only have one `@`.

```
function containsJustOne(original_string, string_to_search_for) {
    var first_location = original_string.indexOf(string_to_search_for);
    if (first_location >= 0) {
        // move 1 spot after our first found index
        var second_location = original_string.indexOf(string_to_search_for, first_location + 1);
        // We want to return true if we DIDN'T find a second location,
        // aka, if it is equal to -1.
        return (second_location === -1);
    } else {
        // We didn't find any, return false right away.
        return false;
    }
}
```

OK! So, we can make a function no, `validateEmail(email)` like so:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    return (containsJustOne('@') && contains('.'));
}
```

Just for fun, if you wanted to solve this with Regular Expressions, I'd maybe do something like this:

```
function validateEmailWithRegExp(email) {
    return /^[^@]*@[^@]*$/.test(email) && /^(?:.*\.)+.*$/.test(email);
}
```

One-liners are fun! That isn't nearly the most optimized reg exp you can use, but it gets the job done per your post.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, that has really explained it well , i have a very long winded function at the moment.